# simultate the iphone lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, lockscreen, core-motion

I'm trying to emulate the ios lock screen, I already have the slide to unlock and lock screen done but I have no idea how to make the transition between the 2, I want it to look exactly the same annimation as the real one, the lock pad appear from the bottom pushing the slide to unlock up, at  the same time the slide is pushed to the left by the password field 
can anyone help on how to achieve this as i'm very new to animation and core motion
thank you in advance

let me change the question, I want to do the same as the annimation that happen when you slide the slide to unclock and the lock screen appear.
The slide to unlock is moving from right to left at the same time the text field is appearing replacing the slide to unlock while he keyboard appear.

Comment: Sounds to me like a reason for the app being rejected by the app store review team.

Answer (score 3):

refer a Opensource how to implementation Slide To cancel. [Slide to Cancel](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/SlideToCancel)

Comment: Thank you, but my question was how to build the transition from the slide to unlock to the lock screen

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at **WWDC 2013 session 217** "**Exploring Scroll Views on iOS 7**".

They talk about how they build lock screen in that video.

Also you might find helpful my project that mimics Lock screen -> Camera transaction

https://github.com/haawa799/iOS7LockScreenCameraLikeTransition